# Quarter circle arc

Tags: circles

[image]

These are congruent sectors (aka quarter circle) with the arc of the lower circle bisects the radius of the upper circle and the radii are parallel. My question is: Is the overlapped part a quarter circle?

My opinion: The arc of the overlapped segment belongs to the circle with point$A$ so it is not a sector

Comment: Your thought is correct

Comment: Curvature of a circle depends on its radius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intersection of the two quarter circles was a *circular sector*, let alone a quarter circle, the angle between the straight lines and the arc would be $90^\circ$. It is rather obvious from the diagram that that angle is less than $90^\circ$. So the intersection is not a quarter circle.